# IIS has no access to Certificate Store

Tags: .net, iis, x509certificate, iis-express

[image: IIS Exrepss vs IIS 10]

I am not very familiar with IIS or Visual C#,

But recently i wanted to wrap a service controller within a .dll file in a web service that we can consume in our cloud app.

I wrote a short script to post the information on a Http WebAPi in C# and wrapped the function of the depending assembly in it.

Locally in my computer i can access the certificate store. Even when i run the app.exe or from IIS Express in localhost:5000 it works as web app can see the certificate keystore.

When i run it from the IIS 10 or from the server public ip it does not recognize the certificates.

> The image is in the same localhost within the server. Running on IIS Express from webbapp.exe on the left and IIS10 on the right.

**Any idea what is going wrong with IIS as per comparison with IIS Express locally?** Can i do anything to fix it or should i find any other workaround.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Keep in mind which user account is used and which store the code tries to access are completely different in such cases.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Sure there would be permission differences but those are a lot of differences.

Comment: @LexLi you are right when i try to print the Certificates in the Store locally i get the certificates when IIS runs the list is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LexLi suggested IIS is limited to the access of the KeyStore. The Configuration was running so that the dll was trying to access the

```
X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
```

The problem was that ISS does not have access to that User for security purposes.
After a few tweaks in the i changed to:

```
X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```

And in the IIS 10 "Application Pool" Under "Advances Settings" of my running application pool. I did the following

```
Identity: LocalSystem
Load User Profile: True
```

Everything seems to be working now.